# How to automatically display folder contain images using html java script jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be display html webpage all images from contain  images folder
it is possible  using HTML,CSS,Java script,Jquery

without php ?

Thanks & Regards
Jejai

Comment: Please, show some effort first. I suggest you to check [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705362/html5-javascript-how-to-create-a-gallery-photo-with-all-file-in-a-folder/ ,

Answer (score 1):

> HTML,CSS,Java script,Jquery

are languages executed on the client's side, on other words on the computer from which the site is accessed. If that was possible that would mean your computer would have to have access to the server's file system (end of the internets).

So no. You can't do server's file listing with only those languages. You need a language which is executed server-side.

*Note:*
*You can achieve this behavior with a setting on the web server (google: "[your web server] allow directory listing"), but that should be probably answered elsewhere, since it's not programming related.*